# I am not getting complete information of logs on my APM dashboard elastic search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, elk, apm

I am trying to log transactions in my APM dashboard related to each user distinguishly. I want to assign a unique id to any user who is using this app and i want to log the user's activities based  on this same id. but i am no getting my desired results. I am getting th euser id but i am not getting the label name.

this is where i am initially creating my setup of APM.

```
import { init as initApm } from "@elastic/apm-rum";
var apm = initApm({
  // Set required service name (allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _, and space)
  serviceName: "Match-maker-game",

  // Set custom APM Server URL (default: http://localhost:8200)
  serverUrl:
    "https://2e8741d8aa7545a59af0a82c8c0b2ff1.apm.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:443",
  // Set the service version (required for source map feature)
  serviceVersion: "1.0.0",

  // Set the service environment
  environment: "cheetay-games",
});

export default apm;
```

Now in my App component i am using APM to log all the events of users based on their unique id's.

```
    import apm from "./apm";
    import { withTransaction } from "@elastic/apm-rum-react";
    function App({ background, wrongAns, correctAns, deadSound, winSound }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Generate a unique user ID
        const userId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
        console.log(userId);
        // Add the user ID to the APM user context
        apm.setUserContext({
          id: userId,
          name: `User ${userId}`,
          custom: {
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
          },
        });
      }, []);
    const handleChoice = (card) => {
        cardClick = cardClick + 1;
        if (cardClick === 1) {
          var event = {
            event_type: "GAME_START",
            score: null,
          };
          eventHandler(event);
        }
        setTimerStart(true);
        setRestartTimer(false);
        setLoseRestartTimer(false);
        background.loop = true;
        //  checking if the counter is one only then set sound to true when the card is flipped for first time
        count === 1 ? setPlaySound(true) : setPlaySound(playSound);
        //  after that increment the counter so that the upper condition should not hold anymore
        setCount(count + 1);
        choiceOne ? setChoiceTwo(card) : setChoiceOne(card);
        const transaction = apm.getCurrentTransaction();
        if (transaction) {
          transaction.addContext({
            name: "card-click",
            type: "user-interaction",
            custom: {
              timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
              level: level,
            },
          });
        }
      };
     return ( 
 <div className="card-grid">
                  {cards.map((card) => (
                    <SingleCard
                      key={card.id}
                      card={card}
                      handleChoice={handleChoice}
                      flipped={
                        card === choiceOne || card === choiceTwo || card.matched
                      }
                      disabled={disabled}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
     );
    }
    export default withTransaction("app", "component")(App);
```